# Reduce high pitched noise from idle stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I have the following setup:

**Stepper motor:** Bipolar, 200 Steps/Rev, 42×38mm, 2.8V, 1.7 A/Phase - https://www.pololu.com/product/2267

**Diver**: DRV8825, *with current limiter VREF = 0.85v* - https://www.pololu.com/product/2133

**Power Supply:** 12v 2a DC

When the steppers are hooked up to the power supply they make a very annoying high pitched noise while the steppers are **idle**. I am fine with a bit of noise while the stepper is moving, but would like them to be silent while stationary. I cannot figure out what is causing the noise. Here is what I have tried to reduce the idle noise:

- Reducing the current until the noise is gone (resulted in complete loss of torque when the current was low enough to remove the noise)
- Used a 5v 3a DC power supply (motor did not power on at all with this supply, I am still confused why it is rated for 2.8v but won't work with 5v but will work with 12v)
- Engage the sleep pin while the motor is not moving (removed the noise while idle, but when it disengages sleep pin to move again its jolts slightly and causes the step count to be off and over time the motor is no longer accurate)

These are not the only stepper motors that I have that have this noise issue, the only motors I have that do not have this noise issue are smaller 350mA neema17's and I think that is just because it has a lower amperage.

I have not been able to find a way to fix this issue. Are my configurations incorrect? What power supply should I be using? Is there anything else I can do to fix this high pitched noise while the stepper is idle. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you driving the DRV8825? I assume you have a micro controller. Can you please provide us some details? Also is the stepper getting hot. Also how are you driving the stepper. Are you using a P
W

Comment: Are you using PWM or just controlling the bits to H-Bridge.

Comment: Re: Didn't work with 5V -- [DRV8825 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf?ts=1620821206837) specifies 8.2V minimum supply

Comment: Re: noise - experiment with varying the supply voltage, microstep setting, and current level. For this driver, I believe the PWM frequency is roughly fixed 30kHz typ, but it may deviate if some internal limits are reached. In particular, your 2A supply won't be able to hit 1.7A per winding (probably 1.7*sqrt(2) when at a half-step position ... if noise is every other half-step position, that is a dead giveaway of this). Anyway start by reducing the 0.85 Vref to around 0.4V, with no mechanical load on shaft, and then play with the microstep settings.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! As for driving the DRV8825 I have both a teensy 3.6 and a RPi 3. I am not using PWM, instead I am just pulsing the STP pin since I need control over the exact position. Will playing with the microstepping change anything while idle (I am only concerned with the noise while the stepper is idle)? I did not see the 8.2 min voltage, so I will also try using a 9v supply.

Comment: Run it in half-step mode, and check if there is more noise idling at every other half-step position.

Comment: I lowered the VREF to 0.4v and put it in half step position, every other step was silent! Does this mean that my power supply is too much and I should lower the voltage?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say so. 0.4V should be 0.8A per winding, so absolute max 1.6A at the half step position. Try to reduce Vref even lower, see if that makes it quiet at every half-step. If so get a bigger power supply.

Comment: What do you mean by “bigger power supply”? More amps or volts?

Comment: amps or both, or alternatively same specs but  physically larger, in case the supply out Z and circuit input Z are resonant at the pwm frequency (which would cause you to top out at less than the rated power), though that's a longshot. Also double check wiring, and if you have another motor of the same type, try that in case of defect

Comment: Tried with 3 other steppers and the noice was present on all. Lowering the amps at half step until the noise does not occur makes the torque too low for my purpose. Would getting a bigger supply but keeping the current limiter low improve the torque?

Comment: I would try that. But how low did you have to reduce it to stop the noise?

Comment: I had to reduce it to between 0.2-0.25V, I also noticed that the angle that I held the stepper would sometimes change the volume of the noise

Comment: That seems too low... Looking further I found [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/370051/271493) ... you may want to follow the trail from that. If you have one available, try a bigger supply anyway - I have seen bigger / differently reactive power resolve mysterious stepper issues, but that's kindof a shot in the dark. It seems like it could be a circuit issue.

Comment: I will look into that, thank you for taking the time to help me out with this problem, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Any further results? It's always okay to answer your own question in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this will work for your particular combination of drive board and motor, but you could try shunting the motor terminals with a capacitor that filters off the squeal signal. However, I would try *first* the other remedies suggested in the comments section.